# QGIS Plugins PIP extension

Tags: qgis, extensions, pip

I have recently been programming in QGIS plugin with python using an extension from pip package management. I installed this extension "browserhistory" manually via the OSGeo4W shell.
However, when I now want to pass this plugin to someone else, he gets the error message: "No module named browser-history". How can I modify the code of the plugin in such a way that this pip extension is automatically installed when the plugin is installed on another computer? So that the other person does not have to install pip manually.

Comment: How do you tranfer  your plugin? zip-File?

Comment: yes exactly ! and then I am using the function "Installing out of zip-file"

Comment: Since there is no official way to accomplish your task, for browserhistory the chance exists to put it as submodule into your plugin, because it seems not to have any dependencies. Try to copy browserhistory.py into your plugin folder and import it with `from . import browserhistory`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help ! Where can I find the browserhistory.py ? Is there a specific directory I can search in ?

Comment: If you already installed browserhistory, it's under apps/python37/lib/site-packages. The code can be found also on GitHub, but I don't have a link available right now.

Comment: But when I navigate to the folder of browserhistory, there is not only one python file, there are four of them. Should I copy them all ?

Comment: As far as I can see you'll only need browserhistory.py, I didn't install the package,  but I made a minimal QGIS plugin, containing that module. I imported it and called one of it's functions. That worked.

Comment: But in my python sitepackages is no browserhistory.py in my browserhistory sitepackage. There is only a __init__.py, browsers.py, cli.py, generic.py and utils.py. Is it possible that you share with me what you exactly have in this browserhistory.py-file ?

Comment: I fear we are not talking about the same module. But you can still try the trick. Though I don't know if there are dependencies in your package. Anyway, in your case you have to copy the hole directory as a subfolder into your plugin directory do make a proper import.

Comment: Yes I think we are talking about another module, I tried to copy the complete folder in my directory; How is the import called then exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A QGIS plugin, written in python is a same as writing a python package, but it has no installation like a package usually has (pip, setuptools). So plugin developer, who wanted to include third-party-modules/packages can't resolve that dependencies.

Though there are functions within a python standard installation, that can be used from within python code to "install" third-party modules. You may use one of the solutions discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code, so each time the plugin is loaded by QGIS, you'll check if it can be imported, otherwise you install it.

For the specific package, browser-history, a simpler solution exists. Because that package has no further dependencies, you can integrate it into your Python plugin, by copying the whole package directory as a subfolder into the plugin folder. By doing this you'll get a package containing another package. So when importing `browser_history` inside your main plugin module you'll use a relative import (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

This looks like this, for example:

```
from . import browser_history
```

To generalize the problem: each python module or packages which has no further dependencies, can be integrated into a Python plugin, but it is not more than a workaround with advantages and disadvantages. Furthermore, if you try using pip inside your code, especially under Windows, using OSGeo4W, the use of pip may fail, when dependent modules use a C-Compiler for installation for example. That's why many python packages can be installed using the setup utility that comes with QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stand-alone Python executable.  This will work for libraries that are not proprietary (like arcpy) [See this link](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/).  Unfortunately, this will result in a rather large file since the entire Python interpreter will be packaged as well.  Furthermore, you will need to locate the EXE inside the resulting file structure.

Better would be to package your project as a Python installation.  Here are some links to get you started. This works if the libraries you want to pass on are available at PyPI and you have those setup.py and requirements.txt file correct.  Still, the user would need to download your installer folder.  Navigate to that location at the command line, and enter the `python setup.py install` stuff to get that stuff installed.

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419607/how-to-automatically-install-required-packages-from-a-python-script-as-necessary/46419642

Comment: QGIS plugins are python packages with an Interface to Qgis, so the "executable option" does not work. Furthermore the plugin will be called from a fixed place inside the user profile. At least the plugin has no installation routine, it is just unpacked into the profile path.

Comment: Yeah thats true. I think converting my plugin into an "exe"-file won't solve the problem !

Comment: @Andreas Muller - Thanks for the clarification.